# Add a plugin before main container

Tags: plugins, php, functions, pages

If I have a plugin that prints (simply) "Hello World", and I want it be outside of the main container, so, like this:

```
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
<div id="content">
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

How can I make that work?

I created a child-theme and I don't want to edit the parent theme files (if even needed).

I saw a solution that you can do something like this:

```
add_action('__before_main_container', 'my_func', 0);
```

(In the *functions.php* file)
and `my_func` would print some html, but that is not working for some reason (it doesn't display anything in the page).

Another thing with this, the plugin I use needs to be added like so:

```
[plugin id="1"]
```

to the page I want it be on.
The problem with this is I cant just do:

```
echo '[plugin id="1"]';
```

because that would not trigger the plugin!

So, what can I do to make that work?

(I want to do this because I want something specific full-width but not the container itself)

EDIT:
Ok I saw that I can override *header.php*, that's great, but how can I insert the plugin there only for specific pages? or pages that include:

```
[plugin id="1"]
```

for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like you're using shortcode to execute your plugin.  so instead of just

```
echo '[plugin id="1"]';
```

use this:

```
echo do_shortcode('[plugin id="1"]');
```

put this in the php file where you want it to load. For example, right above the

```
<div id="content">
```

this can be in whatever file you wish to execute the shortcode

Comment: How can I do this only for pages that include that `[plugin id="1"]`?

Comment: holw are you determining which pages will have that plugin loading?  pages, posts, homepage, blogpage, cpts etc?

Comment: I wanted to determine that by the page content (like regular plugins do) but I eventually did it just with the is_front_page() function. If you have any other idea please let me know :)

Comment: no, if you only want it on the front page that is the best way.  Plugins do it like that too. The is_front_page would just be in their code.  We're pulling it a bit later but the result is the same.